# Is recommending specific brands a bad thing?

Tags: discussion

Is recommending specific brands a bad thing, or is it situational?

(“Brands” referring to anything branded; Programs, products, etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not at all. I have done so in several answers on several different sites across the network. Just work it into your answer, and the explanation. Don't just post a link to a product.

For example, if you search for "Stronglifts" you will get many answers featuring/recommending it.

You can even promote (if relevant) your own product/website, as long as it isn't excessive, and you make full disclosure of the affiliation. It also needs to be in the context of an answer, not just promoting the site.